# Laravel eloquent relationship show only last raw, (Attempt to read property "price" on bool)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new in Laravel.
I have two table 1- Product  2- Product_Price. I want to show the last product Price in Product Page but I tried different methods but getting errors.

My controller code:

```
public function show(Request $request, Product $product): View
{
    $this->authorize('view', $product);
    $ProductTags = $product->ProductTags;
    $ProductPrice = $product->ProductPrices->last();

    return view('app.products.show', compact('product', 'ProductTags', 'ProductPrice'));
}
```

My blade code is:

```
@foreach ($ProductPrice as $productprice)
    <div>
        {{ $productprice->price }}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

But I am getting this error:

> Attempt to read property "price" on bool

Comment: use latest : $ProductPrice = $product->ProductPrices->latest(); and you are not eager loading this. there is one more effiecnt way, create another relationship and with latest and load that relationship in the show

Comment: Try eager loading:
$product = Product::with('ProductPrices', 'ProductTags')->find($product->id);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ProductPrice = $product->ProductPrices->last();`

This gives you a single object, not a collection. You don't need to loop over in the view to get object values.

```
<div>
    {{ $ProductPrice->price }}
</div>
```

This will give the expected output.

> When you loop over an object, the value of the loop variable is boolean. Hence you are getting the error.